# Yesterday Code, broke today (MySQL, PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

i am currently working on a project, and i tried my best to avoid asking question here, but i have currently no idea what's going on.

Yestereday, I did a simple things, which was working and today, i just changed one thing and it's all broken.

```
  elseif (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$name = $bdd->quote($_POST['name']);
echo $name;

$bdd->query("CREATE TABLE ${name} (
  id int(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  entreprise VARCHAR(255),
  nom VARCHAR(255),
  prenom VARCHAR(255),
  fonction VARCHAR(255),
  mail VARCHAR(255),
  mobile VARCHAR(20),
  fixe VARCHAR(20),
  entite VARCHAR(255))
  ");
... }
```

So this is the code, it works perfectly, the $name is the good one, there is no error message but it's not working.

The only major change i did was to remove the connexion part in the file and i put it in an include file

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'myusername', 'mypassword');
```

I really don't think it comes from that, since when i undo it, it's still doesn't work

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you expect us to guess the error you have?

Comment: Well, not really, i was mostly hoping someone who had experiment this kind of issue in the past could share what he did, maybe it will give me some idea, and things to try

Comment: Ok, but what are the errors? Have you turned on the error reporting?

Comment: Yeah and there is none, the code correctly display the name of the variable, and then correctly execute the code after which switch to the next page, nothing shows up.

Comment: So what's the code of "the next page" which you say isn't working? Also, a white screen can mean lots of different things, enable error reporting / check your error logs / provide _that_ code etc etc.

Comment: Well, no sorry i misexplained. The error logs didn't catch any error relevant to this part (i just tried the code again at 10:48) and the last error is at 10:41.
After the creation of the table, there is some js that display a message that tell "the table has been succesfully created" and redirect you to the main page. So it's not a blank page, i can share it if needed but this other page is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLLY!!! I found out

Well this was some dumb mistake from my part and a wrong understanding of the function quote (i thought it was used to replace the mysql_escape_string) but in the end, it doesn't suit a query since it adds quote and quote doesn't work with SQL.

Anyway, thanks for your help

I can eat in peace now :p

Comment: who cares about sql injection anyway?

Comment: I don't know, i thought it was a good habbit to have to limit user possibility.